# REST - Could not find controller on PUT

Tags: services, updating, 8

I'm trying to update a node via REST PUT but failing with the "404 controller not found" error. I have tried everything I know of but still getting the same error.

(No problem on retrieve / index)

Module:

```
function demoapp_feedback_update($edit, $account, $category) {
  cache_clear_all('demoapp_device_validate_pairing_' . $account->uid, 'cache', TRUE);
  cache_clear_all('demoapp_feedback_load_feedback_article_', 'cache', TRUE);
  cache_clear_all('demoapp_feedback_find_feedback_articles', 'cache', TRUE);
}

function demoapp_services_resources() {
  return array(
 'demoapp_feedback' => array(
  'retrieve' => array(
    'help' => 'Retrieves a feedback article',
    'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'demoapp', 'name' => 'resources/feedback_resource'),
    'callback' => 'demoapp_resources_feedback_retrieve',
    'access callback' => 'demoapp_resources_feedback_access',
    'access arguments' => array('retrieve'),
    'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    'args' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'article_id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'description' => 'The id of the feedback article to get',
        'source' => array('path' => '0'),
        'optional' => FALSE,
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'view_mode',
        'type' => 'int',
        'description' => 'Defines what data fields to return',
        'source' => array('param' => 'view_mode'),
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'default value' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'index' => array(
    'help' => 'Retrieves a listing of feedback articles',
    'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'demoapp', 'name' => 'resources/feedback_resource'),
    'callback' => 'demoapp_resources_feedback_index',
    'access callback' => 'demoapp_resources_feedback_access',
    'access arguments' => array('index'),
    'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    'args' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'view_mode',
        'type' => 'int',
        'description' => 'Defines what data fields to return',
        'source' => array('param' => 'view_mode'),
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'default value' => 0,
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'checksum',
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'Checksum of the local data',
        'source' => array('param' => 'checksum'),
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'default value' => NULL,
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'offset',
        'type' => 'int',
        'description' => 'Offsets a list by X number of items',
        'source' => array('param' => 'offset'),
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'default value' => 0,
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'limit',
        'type' => 'int',
        'description' => 'Limits a list by X number of items',
        'source' => array('param' => 'limit'),
        'optional' => TRUE,
        'default value' => 10000,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'actions' => array(
    'update_poll' => array(
      'help' => 'Update a poll',
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'demoapp', 'name' => 'resources/feedback_resource'),
      'callback' => 'demoapp_resources_feedback_update_poll',
      'access callback' => 'demoapp_resources_feedback_access',
      'access arguments' => array('update_poll'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'node_id',
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The id of the node',
          'source' => array('data' => 'node_id'),
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'default value' => 0,
        ),
        array(
         'name' => 'vote',
         'type' => 'int',
         'description' => 'The vote chid',
         'source' => array('data' => 'chid'),
         'optional' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

(Inc: nothing to see here)

Resource:

```
function demoapp_resources_feedback_update_poll($node_id, $chid) {
  global $user;
  global $demoapp_device;

  if (demoapp_validate_not_empty($node_id)) {
    if (!demoapp_validate_not_empty($node_id) || !demoapp_validate_not_empty($chid)) {
  services_error(RESOURCE_ERROR_400_MESSAGE, 400);
    }
  }
  //

  $retrievedVoteID = $chid;

  $node = node_load($node_id);
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

  $selectedVote = $node_wrapper->poll[$chid]['chvotes'];
  $newVote = (int)$selectedVote + 1;

  $node_wrapper->poll[$chid]['chvotes']->set($newVote);
  $node_wrapper->save();

  watchdog('Poll update', 'Retrieved poll update query', $variables = array(
    'Node id' => $node_id,
    'Node object' => $node,
  ), $severity = WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL);

  // Event (POLL_VOTE)
  $event = new demoappEvent();
  $event->type = 'POLL_VOTE';
  $event->name = NULL;
  $event->device_id = ($demoapp_device && $demoapp_device->device_id) ?       $demoapp_device->device_id : NULL;
  $event->user_id = $user->uid;
  $event->registered = time();
  $event->created = time();
  $event_id = demoapp_event_create_event($event);

  if (!$event_id) {
    services_error(RESOURCE_ERROR_500_MESSAGE, 500);
  }
  //

  return array('status' => 'SUCCESS:DONE');
}

function demoapp_resources_feedback_access($op, $args) {
  global $user;

  // Authenticate
  demoapp_services_authenticate();
  //

  $access = FALSE;

  switch ($op) {
    case 'retrieve':
      $access = user_access('access demoapp content');
      break;

    case 'index':
      $access = user_access('access demoapp content');
      break;

    case 'update_poll':
      $access = user_access('access demoapp content');
      break;
  }

  return $access;
}
```

Output:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found : Could not find the controller.)
```

- Services & ops enabled
- Index/retrieve works
- Authenticated
- Permissions set up properly

Thanks for your time.

Edit: JS function

```
postOpinion: function(data, onProgress, onSuccess, onAbort, onError){
    var httpHeaders = demoapp.auth.getHttpHeaders();

    var params = {
        node_id: data.nodeId,
        chid: data.vote
    };

    console.log('Params: ', params);

    demoapp.feedbackRemote.restClient.call(config.serverURL + '/' + config.serviceEndPoint + '/demoapp_feedback/update_poll', JSON.stringify(params), {requestMethod: 'PUT', requestDataType: 'application/json', httpHeaders: httpHeaders, responseDataType: 'json'},
        function _onProgress() {
            onProgress(demoapp.feedbackRemote.restClient);
        },
        function _onSuccess(result) {
            onSuccess(result.status);
        },
        function _onAbort() {
            onAbort();
        },
        function _onError(error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            console.log('Sent url: ', config.serverURL + '/' + config.serviceEndPoint + '/demoapp_feedback/update_poll', JSON.stringify(params));
            onError(error);
        }
    );
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PUT** method is only work for creating item, but you didn't define `create` operation in [`hook_services_resources`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21services%21docs%21services.services.api.php/function/hook_services_resources/7).

If you want to update node, please use **POST** method and define `post` operation instead.

```
function demoapp_services_resources() {
  return array(
  'demoapp_feedback' => array(
    'create' => array(
      // your custom code
    ),
    'update' => array(
      // your custom code
    ),
  );
}
```